# How to import vault keys and file content of blob into azure functions using logic app

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-keyvault

I am trying to create logic app in which I am fetching keys from vault and file content from blob into Logic app. Now I want to fetch keys and file content in azure java function inside logic app but I am unable to do so.

I fetched the file content and keys into logic app. Now creating azure java function in logic app to consume the same. Not able to fetch them. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I’m Wayne Wang from the Microsoft for Founders Hub team!

From my understanding of your question, it seems you possiblely want to do one of the following:

1. Pass the content and keys to Azure Function written in Java
2. Give hint to Azure Function written in Java, let it fetch the keys and contents itself.

For the first possibility, you can implement with as http Post with json or Put with file, but I would not suggest you do it that way.

- secrets should not passed as parameters between services
- Post from/to serverless services usually have a size limitation of 100MB (after base64)

For the second one, we have an article about visiting Key Vault using Java console. it also applied to java functions.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-java?tabs=azure-cli

and you can also use storage account to deliver file contents between services
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-sdk-for-java-storage-blob-upload-download/upload-download-blobs-java/

Communication from Logic Apps to a Function, you can use a http call, or you can use an async message though "Service Bus"  "Storage Queue" "Event Hub" and other stuff. it is a more open topic.

Hope these ideas can help

Comment: I have *.pem files uploaded to key vault under keys. I am unable to get the option in logic app to get the contents and pass this to azure java function. As per your advise you said, it's not good way to send keys as parameter from one service to other service. What will be the ideal way to decrypt the files which are encrypted outside azure and uploaded to blob and decryption keys in vault.By all the means I want this integration of decryption in logic app with java. Please suggest.

Comment: Hi 

I am not a Java user myself.   I think it is still about using  Key vault libs in Java
 it is good to upload your file to storage, encrypted with a cert you stored in keyvault.    here are something i found in realated topic
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925625/azure-key-vault-certificate-management-using-java

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460906/how-to-fetch-certificate-stored-in-azure-keyvault-using-java

Comment: I think  this .net article can help too.    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault?tabs=dotnet     the lib should be alike on namings

Comment: I got the secret key vault value and file content using header and body of http trigger and it worked. I know passing keys is not ideal approach but for now it's ok to go with this solution.